# What is the coil voltage of this contactor?

Tags: coil, contactor

[image]

Sorry for dummy question but I don't know how to identify the coil voltage necessary to activate this contactor?

Thank you

Comment: You have to turn it, to see the coil spec.

Comment: I have nothing else written

Comment: When I type "lc1 ec 03" in google I get 2M+ hits....

Comment: It's obsolete. Find the new part number [here](https://www.schneider-electric.com/resources/sites/SCHNEIDER_ELECTRIC/content/live/FAQS/361000/FA361768/da_DK/8502PD9501.pdf).

Comment: "I have nothing else written" ??? You have to look on the other side of contactor, there is a sign 24=, 110~, 230~, ...

Comment: @MarkoBuršič To be excessively pedantic, it'd be 24⎓, not 24=.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you see the coil 100-120V ?

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did not saw at first time

Comment: Some of these contactors are sold with coil separate from the rest (to accommodate different coil voltages)  so they don’t mark the other part,